# How to add certain search and replace pattern on filenames with specific strings

Tags: function, vim

I have written a function, which does some search and replace on the file which I am editing. But for certain files (with some specific keyterms in the filename), I need to add some specific search and replace which is restricted to these files.

I need to know how to fix the following code:

```
function! Test()
    " basic search and replace for all the files
    %s/I'll /I will /ge
    " if the filename starts with "blah-" the following additional search and replace needed otherwise not
    if match(readfile(expand('%:t')),"^blah-")
      %s/could'nt /could not /gec
    endif
endfunc
```

And on calling the function `:call Test()` all these patterns will be executed. Hence, I do not need to worry about the specific instructions on certain file types.

Can anybody help me fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no match `-1` is returned from [`match()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#match%28%29). Also, you probably don't need to call [`readfile()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#readfile%28%29) to check the filename. As such, change

```
if match(readfile(expand('%:t')),"^blah-")
```

...to...

```
if match(expand('%:t'), '^blah-') != -1
```

...and your `blah-`files (and only your `blah-`files) will have the extra substitution executed.